# Invoking CustomValidator validation from JavaScript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, customvalidator

I have the following setup, where I am custom validating a textbox. It works fine as long as I am manually typing in the textbox and changing the text and focusing out of the textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbpCity" runat="server"/>     
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvPermanentCity" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbpCity" 
 ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" onservervalidate="Field_ServerValidate"   SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" ToolTip="PermanentCity" />
 <ajaxtoolkitwcsfextensions:ServerSideValidationExtender ID="PermanentCityServerSideValidationExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="cvPermanentCity" />
```

when I try to invoke validation change event from javascript (using JQuery 1.4.2)

```
function copyCity() {
$('#<%= tbpCity.ClientID%>').value = "Some City";
$('#<%= tbpCity.ClientID%>').trigger("change");
}
```

the custom validation is not being invoked.

How can I inovke customvalidator to do validation?

note: I have verified this works on FireFox but not on IE. Please let me know how to fire change event in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer posted to similar question on StackOverflow.

```
var tbPermanentAddressCity = document.getElementById('<%= tbpCity.ClientID%>');
if (tbPermanentAddressCity.fireEvent) {
    tbPermanentAddressCity.fireEvent("onchange");
} else {
    $('#<%= tbpCity.ClientID%>').change();
}
```

Once the onchange event is fired, the CustomValidator picks up and validates the textbox.